# How to pad an array non-symmetrically (e.g., only from one side)?

Tags: python, numpy, pad

There is an example in Numpy's documentation for padding 2D arrays with constants:

```
def pad_with(vector, pad_width, iaxis, kwargs):
    pad_value = kwargs.get('padder', 10)
    vector[:pad_width[0]] = pad_value
    vector[-pad_width[1]:] = pad_value
```

but it works for symmetric paddings **only**. For instance, `np.pad(a, ((2, 2), (1, 1)), pad_with, padder=0)` gives:

```
[[0 0 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 0 0]
 [0 1 1 1 0]
 [0 1 1 1 0]
 [0 0 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 0 0]]
```

**Question:** How can I pad the array only from specific sides (i.e., only left and top sides)? Like this:

```
[[0 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 0]
 [0 1 1 1]
 [0 1 1 1]]
```

Comment: That function is still in the documentation of numpy 3 years latter, i would say is an unintended behaviour.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It turns our that with a simple change we can achieve that:

```
def pad_with(vector, pad_width, iaxis, kwargs):
    pad_value = kwargs.get('padder', 0)
    vector[:pad_width[0]] = pad_value
    if pad_width[1] != 0:                      # <-- the only change (0 indicates no padding)
        vector[-pad_width[1]:] = pad_value
```

Here are some examples:

1. Padding 1 row of zeros (only) to the top:

```
>>> np.pad(a, ((1, 0), (0, 0)), pad_with, padder=0)
[[0 0 0]
[1 1 1]
[1 1 1]]
```

2. Padding 2 rows of zeros, both to the left and right:

```
np.pad(a, ((0, 0), (2, 2)), pad_with, padder=0)
[[0 0 1 1 1 0 0]
 [0 0 1 1 1 0 0]]
```

and so on.